# does get-stream work also with regular react-native project that are not expo based?

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

Get-stream io installation guide provides only expo installation guide, i was wondering if i can use the lib also when my project is not expo based?

meaning, is there a way to do:

`npm i get-stream`
`react-native link get-stream`

and then use the class provided?

Comment: probably good idea to specify if you are trying to use feeds or chat since Stream offer both

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the both feeds and chat SDKs (not sure which one you want to use) without using Expo.

Both Chat and Feeds React Native SDKs are organized into 3 separate packages:

- core (all code and components that are not Expo or Native specific)
- expo (all code and components that work on Expo)
- native (all code and components that work without Native)

ie.

Expo project:

```
npm i expo-activity-feed --save
```

Native code project:

```
npm i react-native-activity-feed --save
```